# Set default account when checkout paypal

Tags: paypal

I have used SetExpressCheckout API on this page https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

I am building a site that the user update their paypal account in my site.
they only can check out by provided account in their profile.

When checkout, is there any way for SetExpressCheckout API to set default paypal account which provided in my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the **EMAIL=** variable when doing *SetExpressCheckout*, but you can't force them to log in with that account. It will also be overridden if they have logged into another account recently.

The only option to force an account when logging in is to use AdaptivePayments. You would set  **senderEmail=** and they should not be able to change it.

For more information see: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/